# Does componentDidUpdate flush in the same tick when causing another render?

Tags: reactjs

When you call `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` or otherwise apply any style to a DOM element, does the second render complete in the same tick such that a user never gets to see the intermediate state?

I am writing something that requires me to perform `setState` to perform a CSS transition, and it seems that I have to rely on using `requestAnimationFrame` to inject a CSS transition property to reliably have the transition kick in (otherwise the browser thinks that the element was rendered in its second state without a transition)

The docs say that `componentDidMount` works this way, but I'm not sure if `componentDidUpdate` does the same thing.